# How to pass GeoJSON array to datatable dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, geojson, html, jquery

I want to pass one GeoJSON file to a dynamically created datatable using Javascript, I am unable to identify the column names in the file. I have tried this:

```
<body>
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
     <tr>

        <th>fC.type</th>
        <th>f.type</th>
        <th>f.prop</th>
        <th>f.geom.type</th>
        <th>geometry.coordinates.0</th>
        <th>geometry.coordinates.1</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

 </table>
</body>

 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').dataTable( {

  "ajax":"data/json_file.json",
  "processing":true,
  "columns": [

    { "mData": "type" },
    { "mData": "features.type" },
   { "mData": "features.properties" },
    { "mData": "geometry.type" },
   { "mData": "geometry.coordinates.0" },
   { "mData": "geometry.coordinates.1" }
  ] 
 });
 });
```

And the GeoJSON file is

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
   {
      "type": "Feature",
       "properties": {},
       "geometry": {
       "type": "LineString",
       "coordinates": [
           [
            40.078125,
            57.136239319177434
           ],
           [
            91.7578125,
            58.99531118795094
           ]
                      ]
                  }
      }
   ]
}
```

[image: Output is shown as]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is stored in the `features` array. You can access that by specifying a custom datasource within the `ajax` property like this: `"dataSrc": "features"`.

I haven't found a way to get the GeoJSON property `"type": "FeatureCollection"` that way, it is outside of the actual data "rows".

The complete code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax":{
      "url":"json_file.json",
      "dataSrc": "features"
    },
    "columns": [
      { data: "type" },
      { data: "geometry.type" },
      { data: "properties.propA" },
      { data: "geometry.type" },
      { data: "geometry.coordinates.0" },
      { data: "geometry.coordinates.1" }
    ]
  });
});
```

Another note, `properties` is another nested object (see docs [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html) and [here](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Objects)) where you will have to be specific with the column names, I used `properties.propA` as an example. There does not seem to be an easy way to simply list them all.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/fxhlwfARJEQjMStbZMGx